# Weird Xpages 404 The requested resource cannot be located error

Tags: xpages

I have an Xpages framework DB that I use to copy from and paste into other dbs.

I just did this and got a very bizarre error. Even if I create a brand new EMPTY Xpage in the database, I get the "Xpages 404 The requested resource cannot be located error" when previewing the Xpage in the client or the web.

I checked the logs and found this entry

```
7/2/14 11:22 AM: Exception Thrown
com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.util.PageNotFoundException: Could not create the page /T.xsp because the class xsp.T could not be found. Please check your spelling.
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(Unknown Source)
```

What?

I have cleaned the db, changed the name of the Xpages, etc. All to no avail.

What is going on?

Comment: You tried a project clean and build, I take it?

Comment: What Eric says: did you do a build?

Comment: Yes. Both. And completely closed down Domino. It is very weird. To temporarily get around this I copied my XPages Framework db to a new db and moved the individual design elements from the lotus database over to the new one. This will work for this project, as there are only about 3 design elements. But this will not work for existing non-XP apps that have hundreds of design elements - I want to be able to just plop in a few CCs and Xpages into those. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

Is it an NSF or an NTF? NTFs cannot be previewed on the web - that's standard for Domino HTTP.

Are you certain the two errors are linked? As far as I know, a 404 error is an HTTP error, from the Domino HTTP task. That's triggered either immediately before or immediately after authentication is checked, and before the XPages runtime kicks in. It's not an XPages error. When an XPages error is logged, it generates an HTTP 500 error.

The other cause I've seen for a 404 error on a new XPage is if there were problems building the project. Then the error shows in Domino Designer for the XPage or a Custom Control on that XPage. But that's an XPage error on building the project in Domino Designer, which means the XPage resource is not available in the NSF for HTTP. (Think of it like saving a new LotusScript Script Library with errors, which it will let you do, then trying to call it from an agent.) It won't log an XPages error to the server console or XPages logs - HTTP won't find the XPage because its classes haven't been built, so it returns an HTTP error and doesn't start the XPages Command Manager.